# Looker : Liquid filters on tags, ABS filter

Tags: liquid, looker

Assign an absolute value in Looker with Liquid.

```
dimension: my_dim {
 sql: -10.12 ;;
 html: {% assign abs_val = my_dim._value | abs %} {{ abs_val }} ;;
}
```

Problem: the minus value is printed out. The absolute value is wanted.

Documentation link: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/abs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Liquid implementation we use in the Looker product is not yet updated to the version that includes those math filters— We're working on getting it updated.

Thanks for calling that out! Come hang out at discourse.looker.com if you've got any more Looker-y questions :)

Comment: Any updates on this?